# List Box not sending correct output

Tags: c#

I am making a program that calculates a population's increase over time and I am having issues with some part of my code.

Here is the major part of my code:

```
    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int averageIncrease, numberOfDays, approximatePopulation, increasePercent, count;
        if (int.TryParse(startingTextBox.Text, out approximatePopulation))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(increaseTextBox.Text, out averageIncrease))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(daysTextBox.Text, out numberOfDays))
                {
                    increasePercent = (averageIncrease / 100);
                    count = 1;
                    do
                    {
                        outputListBox.Items.Add(count + "\t " + approximatePopulation + "\t" + increasePercent);
                        approximatePopulation = (approximatePopulation + (approximatePopulation * increasePercent));
                        count++;
                    }
                    while (count <= numberOfDays);
```

[Here is my output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6S51.png)

It seems that it isn't getting the correct increasePercent as it sets it to 0 everytime. I'm not really sure what I have done wrong. from what I can tell, my math and code is correct. I have tried a do-while loop and a for loop.

Comment: Change `increasePercent` type to `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're making integer division, which will return an integer which means in any case you will always lose the floating point.

Example:

```
20/100 = 0.2; // Which will result in 0 (integer remember?)
20/10 = 2; // Will result in 2.0 but 2
25/10 = 2; // Again not 2.5 but 2.
```

What you actually want is to divide with one of the number as a floating point.

```
increasePercent = (averageIncrease / 100.0); // I've added .0 so it will be clear it's a floating point variable.
```

Comment: Will not work in the OP case, since `increasePercent` is of type `int`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, along with the suggestion in the comments from Fabio, I also suggest you make `averageIncrease` a decimal. Along with that, change your equation to something like this:

```
increasePercent = (averageIncrease / 100m)
```

where `m` tells C# that that 100 is a decimal value.

On the other hand, if you want to show a decimal in a string, try using `string.format` like this:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00##}", [DecimalValue])
```

The `0`s are required decimal places and the `#`s are optional :)

In your case, try doing it like this:

```
string listItemValue = string.Format("{0}\t {1}\t{2:0.00##}", count, approximatePopulation, increasePercent);
```

Then add it to your list box like so

```
outputListBox.Items.Add(listItemValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`increasePercent` should of type `decimal`.
And since other variables value based on `increasePercent` they should be declared as decimals as well.

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parsing = new[]
    {
        decimal.TryParse(startingTextBox.Text, out decimal approximatePopulation),
        decimal.TryParse(increaseTextBox.Text, out decimal averageIncrease),
        int.TryParse(daysTextBox.Text, out int numberOfDays),
    };

    if (parsing.All())
    {
        decimal increasePercent = averageIncrease / 100;
        int count = 1;
        do
        {
            outputListBox.Items.Add(count + "\t " + approximatePopulation + "\t" + increasePercent);
            approximatePopulation = (approximatePopulation + (approximatePopulation * increasePercent));
            count++;
         }
         while (count <= numberOfDays);
    }
}
```